# cakePHP custom view folder

Tags: cakephp

I have a UsersController and index() action so by default cakePHP will look for the index.ctp in Users view folder. What i would like to do is to create a separate folder called Partials and have the controller look for the view inside the folder instead. Please help as I just started my journey in cake. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Please do response when someone tries to solve your problem or try to help you ...

Comment: sorry for late reply i posted the comment when i was about to go out of the office. Yeah my boss is planning to use cakePHP and there is an existing system who does not use the cakePHP naming convension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the path to your view by `$this->viewPath` in your controller action. E.g. for the following folder strucuture:

[image: custom view paths]

... you can access the various templates by the following statements:

```
function index()
{
    // by code conventions this action automatically matches /Home/index.ctp

    $this->viewPath = "/Partials/"; // matches /Partials/index.ctp
    $this->render("mypartialview"); // matches /Partials/mypartialview.ctp
}
```

Comment: You can also (not clear from the question the exact intention) add extra paths to where CakePHP looks for view files with [App::build in the bootstrap](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.7/app/Config/bootstrap.php#L41). +1.

Comment: thanks for the answer. by the way the folder view structure is views->themed->partials->users->index.ctp

Comment: consider this as an answered question. Thanks a lot Simon the Sourcecodere

Comment: sorry im kind of new. I did click the green check mark I think that put an end to this question of mine :)